# Error in regex when first character is \ works fine with any other character

Tags: java, regex

For a project that I am doing I have to read a String. This String may contain one or more hexadecimal representations of unicode characters (e.g. "\u0161" for "š"). I want to convert these codes to the correct character representation.

To do this, I first need to detect that there is an hexadecimal sequence of the format "\uAAAA" in my String, and therefor I wrote the following regular expression:

```
Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}");
Matcher classMatcher = classPattern.matcher("\\u1ECD");
System.out.println(classMatcher.find());
```

Unfortunately this generates a " java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal Unicode escape sequence near index 2" error.

However, if I replace the "\", just for testing purposes by an "@" the regex works as expected:

```
Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("@u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}");
Matcher classMatcher = classPattern.matcher("@u1ECD");
System.out.println(classMatcher.find());
```

This leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong with the back slash. I tried also many other sequences, but none of them worked. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The '\u' has a special meaning in the Java regex world, namely around matching actual unicode characters.</strike> You have to double escape the `\` to get the match you desire.

```
Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}");
```

*[update] As comments have pointed out, my reasoning for giving the right answer was flawed.*

Comment: It has nothing whatsoever to do with the following `u` or `\u` meaning anything: Coding a literal backslash into a regex requires 4 backslashes in the java literal String, because the backslashes are escaped twice - once in java and again in the regex.

Comment: This is indeed an example for recommending the right thing for the wrong reason.

Comment: @Bohemian: yep, you're right, read that too fast too early in the morning. Thanks.